# Given two biased samplers, create a less biased sampler

Tags: sampling, algorithms

Suppose you have two biased sampling algorithms, and you don't know the bias of the algorithms. Can you combine the algorithms somehow and reduce the bias?

Partly my motivation is discretizing stochastic differential equations. Say you sample using Euler's method and the Milstein method. Both are biased, but can you combine the algorithms somehow are get a less biased sample?

Another example: suppose you have two MCMC algorithms that are having a hard time converging to the stationary distribution, can you combine the MCMC algos and produce a better algo?

Further motivation: In machine learning, one almost always gets a further improvement by averaging predictions with (ideally) different biases. Now, this is because in ML often our target is a expected value ($E[Y |X]$ or $P(Y|X) = E[ 1_{Y} | X]$), and averages are a great approximation to expected values. Obviously averaging samples does not work, but it there an analogous approach?

Comment: [Any use?](https://www.ideals.illinois.edu/bitstream/handle/2142/11103/Random%20Number%20Generation%20Using%20a%20Biased%20Source.pdf?sequence=2)

Comment: pretty interesting, and it solves some of the class of problems, but I was looking for more generality. This is a good platform though

Comment: [Chapter 2, "The Bootstrap as Bias Reduction Tool,"](http://www.stat.washington.edu/fritz/Reports/bootstrap-report.pdf), might be of some interest.